# Stock market prices not moving after doing Lester Assassination mission #2

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

So, I recently did the Lester Assassination mission #2, the jury one. I remembered to invest in Debonaire, but whilst waiting to get the ROI, I accidentally kicked my PS3's Off button.

When I loaded back in, the game remembered my quick save whilst waiting for the Debonaire market, but after 8 in-game hours, there was no move whatsoever. Even advancing the game clock didn't work... How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

it takes 2-3 days for the stocks to move higher and to pass time just sleep In the game.
P.S. doesn't work on Weekends in game days.

- Lester #1: [BET] 80% ^
- Lester #2: [DEB] sold at 80% ^, (RWC) sold at 300% ^
- Lester #3: [FRT] sold at 50% ^
- Lester #4: [VAP] sold at 100% ^
- Lester #5: [GCD] sold at 80% ^
- Tinkle investment: [TNK] sold at 30%